# Can't render collection in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have some problem. Please, sorry me for my very low JS and Node eperience, i am a newbie in this areas. (And, of course, sorry for my bad english)

I working on my very first Node\Express app, and try to render some templates. I don't like Jade engine (I came from Laravel) and enable Hogan with 'hogan-express'.

I need to render a object collection, that looks like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myEntries));
{"entries": [{"entry":"first"},{"entry":"two"}]}
```

And try to put it to my render like that:

```
res.render('template', {message: 'message', entries: myEntries});
```

And my template:
    {{message}}

```
{{#entries}}
    {{entry}}
{{/entries}}
```

But when I run my app, I see only message, but none of entries! Where I did mistake? Thank's you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You array are stored in property `entries` of object myEntries. So to render you need to pass this property. Example:

```
res.render('template', {message: 'message', entries: myEntries.entries});
```